# Why selection of a Triage's community-specific reason is limited to a list?

Tags: support, triage

Why in StackOverflow's [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/), when I try to set helpful flag `Needs author edit`, choose `A community-specific reason` and then I select `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` I see only this list?:

- belongs [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)
- belongs [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/)
- belongs [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)
- belongs [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)
- belongs [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

When are the choice of other communities?

Comment: You stumbled on a question that would thrive on Beer, Wine & Spirits?

Comment: @rene It's really witty!;) But, unfortunately, I have not yet met such a case.

Comment: Unfortunate indeed. Cheers!

Comment: I mean, smarmy retort aside, plenty of questions that go on stackoverflow belong on askdifferent, unix, softwareengineering, codereview, etc. Options that are not available choices. The answer provided in the dupe is, quite frankly, pathetic.

Comment: some mods don'*t want questions from SO, as they have the experience that it costs more time than benefits. i would like to through questions from other laguages to appropriate site, but they can't be choosen.